# Dreamweaver convert frames to divs

Tags: iframe, dreamweaver

I have an index.html that's split into 3 frames. I want to change it to divs. The "convert tables to ap divs" is grayed out, is there anything I can do? I was following the instructions from here: http://www.ehow.com/how_8598389_convert-frames-divs-dreamweaver.html

If the convert doesn't work for frames is there any other way to do it?

Thanks, AZ

Comment: Frames or iFrames? It really depends on the content of your _frames_ whether this is easily possible or not. Odd reason (to convert frames to DIVs) given on the site you link to: "Dreamweaver lets you convert frames and tables of your website into AP ("absolutely positioned") DIVs so they can be _viewed in older browsers_." !?

Answer (score 1):

You could always go straight into the HTML code via DreamWeaver and change the iFrame tag to a DIV tag.